# WCF Service Returning “Method Not Allowed” while calling from jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, wcf

I am facing strange issue.

i have Web Project URL: "localhost:1111" which calls up another url of another project which is

"localhost:2222/default.aspx" there is wcf service call behind this(default.aspx) page using jquery (ajax).

When "localhost:2222/default.aspx" is direcly starts it works and wcf method works too but when this url is call from another project i get "Method not allowed" error. i think this could be cross domain issue but not sure how to fix it.

**Default.aspx**

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="HTML5TemplateEditor._Default" %>


<script src="js/Jquery-1.11.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/Jquery-ui-1.11.0.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.ui.touch-punch.min.js"></script>
<script>

var url = "http://localhost:19621/TemplateEditorService.svc/" + "VerticalGroupDetails";
alert(url);

$(document).ready(function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: "POST",
        data: JSON.stringify({ Companyid: 1534, templateid: 197, _key: null }),
        dataType: "json",
        processData: false,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        success: function (ListVerticalGroup) {
            VerticalGroupingData = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(ListVerticalGroup.d));
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: how are you calling default.aspx from localhost:1111?

Answer (score 0):

You are not allowed to make cross domain AJAX requests. You have to process AJAX at same domain and make HTTP request (e.g. via CURL) to another domain from the processor part.

Comment: is not the localhost is same domain for both project ? first of all i am calling ajax on same domain the only difference is i am redirecting the url from separate from project but the ajax call is on the redirected url ..

Comment: "localhost:1111" and "localhost:2222" are different domains. The protocol, domain name and port should be identical to be considered same domain. What is the URL of script where you call $.ajax(...)? It should be `http://localhost:19621/...` to pass cross-domain check.